# Text file is empty after writing to it. Getting indexOutOfBound

Tags: java, file-io

Code is asking the user to enter itemName, price, and quantity.  I see it creates a file but no string inside? Is there something wrong with the buffer? Thanks in advance,

userInput:
Enter item name: item1
Enter item price $14
Enter item quantity: 3
Do you want another item? Yes(y) or No(n)n

code:

```
while(userInput.charAt(0)!='n'){
    System.out.print("Enter item name: ");
    itemName = kybd.nextLine();
    PrintWriter out0 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("registryCopy.txt", true)));

    System.out.print("Enter item price $");
    price = kybd.nextLine();
    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("registryCopy.txt", true)));

    System.out.print("Enter item quantity: ");
    quantity = kybd.nextLine();
    PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("registryCopy.txt", true)));


    System.out.print("Do you want another item? Yes(y) or No(n)");
    userInput= kybd.next();
    }//end of whileLoop
```

after editing still the same - no string inside the file:

```
while(userInput.charAt(0)!='n'){
        PrintWriter out0 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("registryCopy.txt", true)));

    System.out.print("Enter item name: ");
    itemName = kybd.nextLine();
    out0.println(itemName);
```

update2: ok so it was the flush at the end out0.flush();  my output is: item1 //nextline, price // nextline, quantity // nextLine... how would I make it stay on the same line so I could later do some manipulations with the hasNext?

Update3:
Getting indexOutOfBound. After sucessfull file save. I open the file to perform the following tasks: find the total costPerItem, totalCount and sum. Don't know why I'm getting out of bound. Error points out to **totalCost =+ Double.parseDouble(index[1].trim());** Source code:

```
Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("registryCopy.txt"));

    while(data.hasNext()){
        String line = data.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        String[] index = line.split("\\t");
        totalCost += Double.parseDouble(index[1].trim());
        totalCount += Integer.parseInt(index[2].trim());

        sum = totalCost/totalCount;

    }
```

Comment: You are not writing any data to the file.... Try using `out0.println(itemName)`. Also you don't need to create three PrintWriters

Comment: out0.print(xyz) did the trick...Ok moving on to the scanner now.

Answer (score 4):

You're not writing to this:

```
PrintWriter out0 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("registryCopy.txt", true)));
```

(or your other 2 writers) but merely opening it ready for writing. Trying writing to it and flushing/closing it.

Check out [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file) for more info on how to write to files.